# C# Search image .bmp inside a window if found then click x, y

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find an image .bmp inside a window ( client ).. using c#
if someone could help me figure this out , it would be very nice ! :)

```
public List<Point> FindImageInImage(int parrentLeft, int parrentTop, int parrentRight, int parrentBottom, Bitmap searchingBitmap)
    {
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
        g.CopyFromScreen(parrentLeft, parrentTop, parrentRight, parrentBottom, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

        var pixelFormatSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmpScreenshot.PixelFormat) / 8;

        // Copy sourceBitmap to byte array
        var sourceBitmapData = bmpScreenshot.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpScreenshot.Width, bmpScreenshot.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmpScreenshot.PixelFormat);
        var sourceBitmapBytesLength = sourceBitmapData.Stride * bmpScreenshot.Height;
        var sourceBytes = new byte[sourceBitmapBytesLength];
        Marshal.Copy(sourceBitmapData.Scan0, sourceBytes, 0, sourceBitmapBytesLength);
        bmpScreenshot.UnlockBits(sourceBitmapData);

        // Copy serchingBitmap to byte array
        var serchingBitmapData =
            searchingBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, searchingBitmap.Width, searchingBitmap.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, searchingBitmap.PixelFormat);
        var serchingBitmapBytesLength = serchingBitmapData.Stride * searchingBitmap.Height;
        var serchingBytes = new byte[serchingBitmapBytesLength];
        Marshal.Copy(serchingBitmapData.Scan0, serchingBytes, 0, serchingBitmapBytesLength);
        searchingBitmap.UnlockBits(serchingBitmapData);

        var pointsList = new List<Point>();

        // Serching entries
        // minimazing serching zone
        // sourceBitmap.Height - serchingBitmap.Height + 1
        for (var mainY = 0; mainY < bmpScreenshot.Height - searchingBitmap.Height + 1; mainY++)
        {
            var sourceY = mainY * sourceBitmapData.Stride;

            for (var mainX = 0; mainX < bmpScreenshot.Width - searchingBitmap.Width + 1; mainX++)
            {// mainY & mainX - pixel coordinates of sourceBitmap
             // sourceY + sourceX = pointer in array sourceBitmap bytes
                var sourceX = mainX * pixelFormatSize;

                var isEqual = true;
                for (var c = 0; c < pixelFormatSize; c++)
                {// through the bytes in pixel
                    if (sourceBytes[sourceX + sourceY + c] == serchingBytes[c])
                        continue;
                    isEqual = false;
                    break;
                }

                if (!isEqual) continue;

                var isStop = false;

                // find fist equalation and now we go deeper) 
                for (var secY = 0; secY < searchingBitmap.Height; secY++)
                {
                    var serchY = secY * serchingBitmapData.Stride;

                    var sourceSecY = (mainY + secY) * sourceBitmapData.Stride;

                    for (var secX = 0; secX < searchingBitmap.Width; secX++)
                    {// secX & secY - coordinates of serchingBitmap
                     // serchX + serchY = pointer in array serchingBitmap bytes

                        var serchX = secX * pixelFormatSize;

                        var sourceSecX = (mainX + secX) * pixelFormatSize;

                        for (var c = 0; c < pixelFormatSize; c++)
                        {// through the bytes in pixel
                            if (sourceBytes[sourceSecX + sourceSecY + c] == serchingBytes[serchX + serchY + c]) continue;

                            // not equal - abort iteration
                            isStop = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (isStop) break;
                    }

                    if (isStop) break;
                }

                if (!isStop)
                {// serching bitmap is founded!!
                    pointsList.Add(new Point(mainX, mainY));
                }
            }
        }

        bmpScreenshot.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        return pointsList;
    }

private static Bitmap CaptureScreenRegion(Rectangle rect)
    {
        Bitmap BMP = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Graphics GFX = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(BMP);
        GFX.CopyFromScreen(rect.X, rect.Y, 0, 0, rect.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return BMP;
    }
```

There's what i'm trying to do.. i don't know if i do it correctly tho, because it doesnt seems to do anything..
i'm just trying to if (found) then mouseclick(x,y)

```
Bitmap Energybmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Gabyy\Desktop\RS3Pixel\data\winrar.bmp");

        //ss PaleWisp = PixelSearch(Rec, int.Parse(PaleColor, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), 5);
        //Point EnergyRift = PixelSearch(MiniMap, int.Parse("4238C5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), 5);
        List<Point> Energy = FindImageInImage(0, 0, 1920, 1080, Energybmp);

        if (Energy.Count >= 1)
            AutoItX.MouseClick("left", Energy[1].X, Energy[1].Y, 1, -1);
```